# Why didn't my Level 1 Barbarian become Level 2 when donated?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am in a level 8 clan which means that if you donate a troop of level 1, it will automatically become level 2. But when I donated a Level 1 Barbarian to a member of my clan, it did not become level 2.

Is this a glitch or what?

[image: Barbarian is still level 1]

Comment: Check with the clanmate you donated it to; maybe the level upgrade can only been seen by the person who received it?

Comment: No, i am sure that everyone can see the level increase in troops

Comment: I've noticed this problem before too, not sure why it happens though.

Comment: Probably bug, Contact supercell and report them.

Comment: Might be lag as well, sometimes donating troops can take a while to apply completely on the receiving end.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted

Comment: Can you confirm by visiting your clanmate's village and viewing their clan castle?

Comment: @Ellesedil I checked it but he got level 1 Barbarians only.

Comment: Probably just a glitch, you should report it on the website.

Comment: @That Man I already did that.

Comment: Why are you donating barbs to a person who's asking for other stuff

Comment: @bleh because he had only 1 space left in his clan castle

Answer (score 1):

This is a very occasion and has happened to me, but once you close and re open the app, the troops will be shown as upgraded. Even if it shows as level 1 to you, he actually received Level 2 Barbarian.

Answer (score 1):

This is a visual glitch where the level of the troops does not appear.

The troop has been levelled up, but you can not see it. This even happens to troops which are higher than level one causing to appear as if they have been downgraded

Reopening the app should fix this